# Importing data to table in specific HBase namespace using Sqoop

Tags: hbase, sqoop

Is it possible to import data to table in specific HBase namespace other than default? I have been searching a lot but could not find anything in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I found this to work for me:

```
    sqoop import -Dsqoop.hbase.add.row.key=true --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@ sqlconnection --username yourname --P --query 'your query' --hbase-table namespace:tablename --column-family COLS --split-by column -m 8 --hbase-create-table
```